# Subsetting multiindex columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with multiindex hierarchical colmn names, including empty strings as column index names. How to subset second and third columns?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3),
                         index=[1,2,3,4,5],
                         columns=[['A', 'A', 'B'],
                                  ['a', 'b', ''],
                                  ['',  'x', '']]
)
df.columns.names = ["c_ix0", "c_ix1", "c_ix2"]
print(df)

c_ix0   A       B
c_ix1   a   b    
c_ix2       x    
1       0   1   2
2       3   4   5
3       6   7   8
4       9  10  11
5      12  13  14
```

expected output:

```
c_ix0      A   B
c_ix1      b    
c_ix2      x    
1          1   2
2          4   5
3          7   8
4         10  11
5         13  14
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: What's you attempt?

Comment: Sorry, my expected output is a DF containing second and third col.

Comment: @BoB - Check edited answer.

Comment: @jezrael - thanks a lot. One more question: knowing only combination of indexes A, B, b, x, "" (empty string)  and not having the serial numbers of columns (needed for .iloc), how would I get the expected output?

Comment: @BoB - Do you think `df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(['b', ''])]` ?

Comment: @jezrael - I'd avoid refering to '' (empty string) because it wouldn't be a unique identifier in general. I thaught rather of a more elegant version of this: pd.concat([df.xs('x', axis=1, level=2), df.xs('B', axis=1, level=0)], axis=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
a = df.xs('b', axis=1, level=1)
print (a)
c_ix0   A
c_ix2   x
1       1
2       4
3       7
4      10
5      13

b = df.xs('B', axis=1, level=0)
print (b)
c_ix1    
c_ix2    
1       2
2       5
3       8
4      11
5      14
```

If want select by positions use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
c = df.iloc[:, 1]
print (c)
1     1
2     4
3     7
4    10
5    13
Name: (A, b, x), dtype: int32
```

EDIT:

```
d = df.iloc[:, [1, 2]]
print (d)
c_ix0   A   B
c_ix1   b    
c_ix2   x    
1       1   2
2       4   5
3       7   8
4      10  11
5      13  14
```